# Calculate number of days passed since First event R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the number of days which have passed since the first event. There are different groups, so each group's starting date for an event is different and I want to calculate each groups number of days passed since their own first event.

```
names = c('Ben',"Ben","Ben","Ben","Ben","Ben" ,'Dan',"Dan","Dan","Dan", 'Peter',"Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter",'Betty',"Betty","Betty",'Betty', "Betty")
dates = c('2000-02-01','2000-02-02',"2000-02-03","2000-02-04",'2000-02-05','2000-02-05', '2000-01-11','2000-01-12',"2000-01-13",'2000-01-14',
           '2000-09-10','2000-09-11',"2000-09-12",'2000-09-13','2000-09-14','2000-09-15','2000-09-16','2000-11-13','2000-11-14', "2000-11-15",'2000-11-16','2000-11-17')
events = c(0,0,1,4,5,11,0,0,2,6,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,3)
newd = data.frame(names,dates,events)
newd
```

so the data frame looks like this:

```
> newd
   names     dates events
1    Ben 2000-02-01      0
2    Ben 2000-02-02      0
3    Ben 2000-02-03      1
4    Ben 2000-02-04      4
5    Ben 2000-02-05      5
6    Ben 2000-02-05     11
7    Dan 2000-01-11      0
8    Dan 2000-01-12      0
9    Dan 2000-01-13      2
10   Dan 2000-01-14      6
11 Peter 2000-09-10      0
12 Peter 2000-09-11      0
13 Peter 2000-09-12      1
14 Peter 2000-09-13      2
15 Peter 2000-09-14      3
16 Peter 2000-09-15      4
17 Peter 2000-09-16      5
18 Betty 2000-11-13      0
19 Betty 2000-11-14      0
20 Betty 2000-11-15      1
21 Betty 2000-11-16      2
22 Betty 2000-11-17      3
```

This is just an example I am using, the 'events' are not in a specific order and are totally random, there are also many other dates with the event of 0. So I would like to only start counting days where: event > 0.
So if there's a 0 at 'event' than there should also be a 0 days counted.

Comment: are your dates always sequential with 1 day interval? If so you can simply do `lengths(split(newd$dates, newd$names)) - 1`

Comment: @Sotos, no they are not, this is just an example.

Comment: That's something you need to specify though in your question :)

Comment: @Sotos , I have updated my data frame and changed it a bit so that my question hopefully comes through more clear.

Comment: `events` is your expected output, right? Why is row 6 11?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the dates to actual date and you can then subtract minimum dates for each `names`.

```
newd$dates <- as.Date(newd$dates)

library(dplyr)
newd %>% group_by(names) %>% mutate(events = as.integer(dates - min(dates)))

#   names dates      events
#   <chr> <date>      <int>
# 1 Ben   2000-02-02      0
# 2 Ben   2000-02-03      1
# 3 Ben   2000-02-04      2
# 4 Ben   2000-02-05      3
# 5 Ben   2000-02-05      3
# 6 Dan   2000-01-12      0
# 7 Dan   2000-01-13      1
# 8 Dan   2000-01-14      2
# 9 Peter 2000-09-11      0
#10 Peter 2000-09-12      1
#11 Peter 2000-09-13      2
#12 Peter 2000-09-14      3
#13 Peter 2000-09-15      4
#14 Peter 2000-09-16      5
#15 Betty 2000-11-14      0
#16 Betty 2000-11-15      1
#17 Betty 2000-11-16      2
#18 Betty 2000-11-17      3
```

In base R :

```
newd$events <- with(newd, dates - ave(dates, names, FUN = min))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(newd)[, events := dates - min(dates), names]
```